# Get Meta-Title, Description & Images.

Tags: php

i have an text-box which allows users to post the url's

```
file_get_contents_curl($url);
```

`$image_regex = '/<img[^>]*'.'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';`

it displays all the images in the url, I would want to show only an image tag of the og:image included in this url.

Answer (score 0):

You can get first match with this code.

```
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$image_regex = '/<img[^>]*'.'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';


preg_match($image_regex, $content, $matches);
$firstImage = strip_tags($matches[1]); // Get first match

echo $firstImage;
```

Comment: it displays unwanted image ,